# Upload NuGet package, how to set the license?

Tags: nuget, licensing

I'm trying to upload a new NuGet package on the website.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/manage/upload

On the first attemp I received an error that says I need to specify the license.
I don't want but... ok.

So, my first attempt with a specified license failed.  I read the linked documentation and I tried multiple times.
I tried with a `<license>` property and also including a license.txt file in the package.

These are my try with the .nuspec file and the error I receive:

```xml
<license type="MIT"/>  
    => Error: Unsupported license type 'MIT'.
    (I know it is wrong but I found this "example" here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Packaging-License-within-the-nupkg)

<license type="expression">MIT</license>   
    => Error: To provide a better experience for older clients when a license expression is specified, must be set to 'https://licenses.nuget.org/MIT'.  

<license type="expression">BSD-2-Clause OR MIT</license>
    => Error: To provide a better experience for older clients when a license expression is specified, must be set to 'https://licenses.nuget.org/BSD-2-Clause%20OR%20MIT'.

<license type="expression">https://licenses.nuget.org/MIT</license>
    => Error: Invalid license metadata: The license expression 'https://licenses.nuget.org/MIT' contains invalid characters.
```

I also tried with my license.txt without success.

What I'm doing exactly is: modify the mylibrary.nuspec file contained in a generated mylibrary.nupkg adding the `<license>` field.
Why? Because this VS studio project generatse the package using nuget.exe mylibrary.csproj file, and it does not contains the license.
I updated nuget.exe to the latest 5.1 version, but I don't want to modify the VS solution or project.

Any idea ?

Comment: These errors are when you upload to nuget.org? Not seeing these errors when I use `nuget pack`. I think the errors for 2) and 3) are just saying that you should also include the older style licenseUrl element for older clients.

Comment: nuget pack is fine, no errors. I have these errors when I use the web site Upload page.
--- "licenseUrl is being deprecated. Use license instead."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#license

Comment: I would file this over against the NuGetGallery - https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Edit the `.csproj` file. Add the following:

**Using License file:**

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE.txt</PackageLicenseFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="licenses\LICENSE.txt" Pack="true" 

PackagePath="LICENSE.txt"/>
    </ItemGroup>
```

**Using PackageLicenseExpression:**

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more details, [see](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Packaging-License-within-the-nupkg)

Comment: Using this package license expression method makes the "License Acceptance" window (in my case) just show a hyperlink to MIT, without any other text, at all. Is this behaviour by design or am I not doing something right?

Comment: @mathgenius maybe you need to specify `<requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>` in your nuspec file?

Comment: `LICENSE` (as opposed to `LICENSE.txt`) may not work with this approach! https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7601

Comment: LICENSE does work if you set the PackagePath=""

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to set two properties:

- `PackageLicenseUrl` - `https://licenses.nuget.org/MIT`
- `PackageLicenseExpression` - `MIT`